# How to Count the number of words over an alphabet subject to restrictions on letter count?

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory

For an alphabet $X$, is there a method of computing how many words over $X$ of length $n$ there are where the number of occurrences of each letter must satisfy a system of equations?

For example if $|X| = 5$. Let ${\{a, b, c, d, e}\}$ represent the number of times each of the five letters appears in a length $n$ word over $X$.

With no restrictions I believe the number of words would be $5^n$.

What about subject to the restriction $2a+2e=2d+2b-c$?

**Edit:**
So I had the idea that we could form a set of prime words, such that every word that satisfies the equation could be decomposed into these smaller words (up to permuting the letters of the original word).

Labelling each of the letters ${A,B,C,D,E}$, this set is $\{AD, AB, ED, EB, DCC, BCC\}$, so there are $4$ prime words of length $2$ and $2$ of length $3$ from which all words satisfying the condition must be composed (up to permutation).

Then we can get the total number by checking the partitions of $n$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline 1 & 0 \\ 
\hline 2 & 4 \\ 
\hline 3 & 2 \\ 
\hline 4 & 4^2=16 \\ 
\hline 5 & 4.2=8 \\ 
\hline 6 & 4^3+2^2=68 \\ 
\hline 7 & 4^2.2=32 \\ 
\hline 8 & 4^4+4.2^2=272 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

Of course with no restrictions the total is now ${{4+n}\choose{n}}$ instead of $5^n$. 
This isn't really the same as the original problem, but maybe it's relevant. Thoughts?

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d,e$ meant as upper bounds or do you mean that each letter appears exactly $a,b,c,d,e$ times respectively? To put it differently, do you mean $n\leq a+b+c+d+e$ or $n=a+b+c+d+e$?

Comment: @String : I think the OP means $a+b+c+d+e=n$

Comment: Hi, perhaps some automata approach using the Chomsky-Schutzemberger theorem. You bound the $n$ (for finitud of the automata), then you create an automaton of $1+n*(\max \lambda _i +|\min \lambda _i|)$ states,where the lambdas are the coefficients of the restriction and where the transitions are made by those coefficients. For example, in your restriction the automata shoud look like a chain where the initial and final state is the 0, if you see a "c", you go to state 1(cause thats the coefficient), if you see an "a" to state 2, if you see a "d" to state -2 and so far.

Comment: I meant what gar said.

Answer (score 2):

extending a little bit the comment i did about using automatas i have not solve the problem itself, but instead we can count the number of words with the example restriction you made (i.e $2a-2b+c-2d+2e=0$) and adding another restriction(for matter of finiteness of the system) which is that for every prefix $x$ of the word, the following must holds $p\leq 2a-2b+c-2d+2e \leq q$

It can be done by solving the following system of formal series for $A_0$

$A_0=1+2xA_2+2xA_{-2}+xA_1$
$A_i=2xA_{i+2}+2xA_{i-2}+xA_{i+1} \hspace{5mm}$ for $i \in [p+2,q-2]\setminus \{0\}$
$A_{p}=xA_{p+1}+2xA_{p+2}$
$A_{p+1}=xA_{p+2}+2xA_{p+3}$
$A_{q}=2xA_{q-2}$
$A_{q-1}=xA_q+2xA_{q-3}$

which is gained by seeing the following automata(in its matrix form cause i do not know how to draw good :P)
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

For example, i have calculated the generating series for words with $q=2,p=-2$ and is $\frac{1-4x^2}{1-12x^2-6x^3+32x^4-8x^5}=1+8x^2+6x^3+64x^4+128x^5+O(x^6)$.

I really like this question and hope to read some cool answer soon :).

Comment: Very interesting answer! But for $n=4$, a direct count gives 96 possibilities ([pasted here](http://pastebin.com/7bi4Fy9s)). Was that generating function for this problem? And thanks for mentioning the theorem, never knew about it!

Comment: @gar Hi, yes i reached the same count as you, but i post with the restriction i mentioned about the prefixes of the words. If you change $q=4,p=-4$, you will get that number. :) Still thinking how to get a closed formula.

Comment: I think I need more time to understand the theorem and your answer. So did you mean for this question the matrix and generating function is different? Can you post the generating function? That gf can be written as a partial fraction decomposition numerically, could not find a solution in terms of radicals.

Comment: Nop, they are the same :) try to exponentiate the matrix and see the coordinate (1,1)..you will see the values. I meant that if you change the values of q and p, the matrix and the system changes, so the answer changes..I erased the result, but i verify it with a script(doing dfs in the automata) so i am sure it gives the same as your count if you move q and p to be 4,-4. If you try to solve the system you will see is a little bit tricky :S, but a systematic way of solving it will lead us to the answer, i guess. What do you mean by "partial fraction descomposition numerically"?

Comment: Okay, I'll read more about it and get back to this. I meant that your generating function can be written as:  $$\frac{{{0.04076597994398540}}}{x - 3.686905113996942}- \frac{{{0.0935883314560565}}}{x - 0.7540756259158595}- \frac{{{0.11271948840723651}}}{x - 0.2996061260107125}+ \frac{{{0.08277091995965379{-}0.0674158217520463\, i}}}{x + {{0.3702934329617569{-}0.11379291047677543\, i}}}+ \frac{{{0.08277091995965379+0.0674158217520463\, i}}}{x + {{0.3702934329617569+0.11379291047677543\, i}}}
$$ from which we can get an approximate formula.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R = a+e$ , $S=b+d$, $T=c/2$ (all are non-negative integers, since $c$ must be even). Then we have the conditions

$$R + S + 2 T=n\\
 R - S +T =0$$

From this system we get:

$$  3 S = n+ R  $$ $$   T = n -2S  $$$$  2 R =  n - 3 T $$

Then $n/3\le S \le n/2$. We can check that, for each integer $S$ in that range we get one and only one solution.

Now, if we fixed $R,S,T$, the number of combinations is $$ \frac{n!}{R! \, S! \, (2T)!} 2^R 2^S$$

Hence the total number is

$$ M=n!\sum_{S=\lceil n/3 \rceil}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{2^S 2^{3S-n}}{(3S-n)! S! (2n-4S)!}=
\frac{n!}{2^n}\sum_{S=\lceil n/3 \rceil}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{16^S}{(3S-n)! \, S! \, (2n-4S)!}$$

A few values

```
n M
2 8 
3 6 
4 96
5 240
10 459648 
20 4081846153216
```

We can get an asympotical approximation by a probabilistic argument. Consider a word is generated at random (uniformly), then the variable $x=2a+2e-2d-2b+c$ can be though as the sum of $n$ iid variables $z$ taking the values $z=\pm 2 $ with probablity $2/5$ and $z=1$ with prob. $1/5$.- This means $E(z)=1/5$ and $\sigma^2_z = 84/25$ and the, for large $n$, $x$ is approximately normal with $E(x)=n/5$ and $\sigma^2_x = n \, 84/25$. Then

And $$M = 5^n P(x=0) \approx  5^n \frac{5}{\sqrt{168 \, \pi n }} \exp{\left(-\frac{n}{168}\right)}$$

The agreement is quite good for $n >20$  (better approximations could be obtained via Edgeworth expansions)

```
 n   5^n/M  ~1/p(x=0)
10  21.245  15.421
20  23.363  23.146
30  30.474  30.086
40  37.451  36.871
50  44.295  43.752
60  51.444  50.867
```